# Custom dependency property not set on initialization

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have UserControl ImageView that I want to add a cutom property called UseOverlay to.

```
<XAML>

<UserControl x:Class="ImageView" .../>

<XAML.cs>
public partial class ImageView : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty UseOverlayProperty;    
    public ImageView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (UseOverlay)
        {
            AddOverlay();
        }
    }      

    static ImageView()
    {
        UseOverlayProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UseOverlay", typeof(bool), typeof(ImageView), new PropertyMetadata(false));
    }

    public bool UseOverlay
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(UseOverlayProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UseOverlayProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

However, when used from another userControl, the property is not set. The ImageView is displayed, but without the overlay, and debugging shows UseOverlay as false.

```
<ImageView MaxWidth="450" UseOverlay="True"/>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you check your output window for any error messages?

Comment: Ye, no errors or warnings related to this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the moment `UseOverlay` used only once in constructor (where it is `false` according to default value). When `UseOverlay="True"` is applied nothing happens. You need to add DP ChangedCallback:

```
DependencyProperty.Register("UseOverlay", typeof(bool), typeof(ImageView),
                            new PropertyMetadata(false, UseOverlayChangedCallback));
```

```
private static void UseOverlayChangedCallback(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((bool) e.NewValue)            
        ((ImageView)obj).AddOverlay();
    else
        ((ImageView)obj).HideOverlay();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you must not use it in the constructor (whithout default value) and use the callback to update the layout

```
#region --------------------Is playing--------------------
    /// <summary>
    /// Playing status
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPlayingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsPlaying", typeof(bool), typeof(WaitSpin),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsPlayingChanged)));

    /// <summary>
    /// OnIsPlayingChanged callback
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private static void OnIsPlayingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(d))
            return;

        WaitSpin element = d as WaitSpin;
        element.ChangePlayMode((bool)e.NewValue);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// IsPlaying
    /// </summary>
    [System.ComponentModel.Category("Loading Animation Properties"), System.ComponentModel.Description("Incates wheter is playing or not.")]
    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsPlayingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsPlayingProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion
```

you can add default with this, replace last part of register

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                       RatingValueChanged)
```